# I want to delete the last two letters form a verb and conjugate it using StringBuilder

Tags: java, stringbuilder

Everything is explained in the comments

```
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

//asking for the verb
System.out.println("Donnez un verbe regulier du premier groupe :");

//putting the verb in the string
String chaine=sc.nextLine();

//taking the two last elements
char first=chaine.charAt(chaine.length());
char second=chaine.charAt(chaine.length()-1);

//creating a StringBuilder:
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

//putting string in the builder :
sb.append(chaine);

//deleting the two last characters :
sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1);


//printing elemnts :
System.out.println("Je "+sb.append("e"));
System.out.println("Tu "+sb.append("es"));
System.out.println("Il/Elle "+sb.append("e"));
System.out.println("nous "+sb.append("ons"));
System.out.println("vous "+sb.append("ez"));
System.out.println("Ils/Elles "+sb.append("ent"));
```

I got `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I can help more according to your questions.

Comment: why use a string builder in the first place? Can't you just use `substring()` to delete the last 2 chars, and then simple concatenation: `stringWithout2Chars + "es"`

Comment: You're right, who gave me the task demands working on StringBuilder, because in companys they Use it a lot.

Comment: Stick to StringBuilder but use substring as well.

Comment: *Everything is explained in the comments* Especially that there are no comments. Please reformat.

Comment: i got StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Thanks for supplying that information, @khmed, it’s very useful. When supplying more information, it’s best to edit the question and add it there. This time I did it for you. And I have retracted my close vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String radical = chaine.replaceFirst("..$", "");

System.out.println("Je " + radical + "e");
System.out.println("Tu " + radical + "es");
System.out.println("Il/Elle " + radical + "e");
System.out.println("Nous " + radical + "ons");
System.out.println("Vous " + radical + "ez");
System.out.println("Ils/Elles " + radical + "ent");
```

This uses a regular expression `replaceFirst`. The pattern:

- `.` any character
- `.` any character
- `$` end of string

Hence: the last two letters are replaced by the empty string.

The minor advantage over `chaine.substring(0, chaine.length() - 2)`
is that for the empty string or one-letter string no indexing error happens;
it does no replacing. Admittedly `substring` is faster.

Comment: One may also want to save that regex into a variable: `static final Pattern LAST_2_CHARS = Pattern.compile("..$");`

Comment: I’d rather consider that a disadvantage: If the input is incorrect, we’d like to be notofied that something is wrong. Of course, this is primarily a question a adding input validation in the first place: `if (chaine.endsWith("er"))`…

Comment: @OleV.V. thanks, a fail-fast is indeed fine in a processing pipe line. (Here I would rather expect `if (chaine.endsWith("er")) ... chaine.substring(0, chaine.length() - 2)` or the laziness of a `replaceFirst`.)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is full of errors.
First:

```
char first=chaine.charAt(chaine.length());
char second=chaine.charAt(chaine.length()-1);
```

Will throw an exception because the last character of `chaine` is `chaine.length()-1`. So you should have written:

```
char first=chaine.charAt(chaine.length()-1);
char second=chaine.charAt(chaine.length()-2);
```

or perhaps:

```
char first=chaine.charAt(chaine.length()-2);
char second=chaine.charAt(chaine.length()-1);
```

but you don't seem to do anything with `first` and `second`.

Next, `StringBuilder.append` will append the parameter to the builder, I don't think that's what you wont.

Perhaps you wanted to do:

```
String prefix = chaine.substring(0, chaine.length()-2);

System.out.println("Je " + prefix + "e");
System.out.println("Tu " + prefix + "es");
System.out.println("Il/Elle " + prefix + "e");
System.out.println("Nous " + prefix + "ons");
System.out.println("Vous " + prefix + "ez");
System.out.println("Ils/Elles " + prefix + "ent");
```

Comment: Also the asker is removing only one character from the string builder: `sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length()-1);`. I would have preferred sb.setLength(sb.length() - 2));`.